# How to pass an interval parameter to a prepared statement?

Tags: postgresql, go, prepared-statement

I want to delete all database entries in my Postgres database that are older than X minutes. My prepared statement in go looks like this:

```sql
delete
from my_table
where expires < (to_timestamp($1) - '$2 minutes'::interval);
```

How can I correctly pass the second parameter `$2`?

---

PS: I know there's different statements to solve the problem, but I am explicitly interested in how to pass parameters that are quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to interpolate a parameter into a string literal.

A possible solution for your case would be to multiply a number with an interval:

```
where expires < (to_timestamp($1) - $2 * '1 minute'::interval)
```

Comment: That's what I feared. (-_-')
At least now I know that I will have to work my way around this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `make_interval`

```
delete from my_table
where expires < (to_timestamp($1) - make_interval(mins => $2));
```

Comment: IMO this is the cleanest solution to this specific problem. Unfortunately, I appears that there's no solution to interpolate parameters into string. Just as @laurenz-albe stated below.

Comment: @MariBowman: you could write your own `create_interval()` function where you pass a string literal and convert it into a proper `interval` value

Answer (score 3):

You can [cast](https://postgresql.org/docs/13/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) the parameter to `text` and then [concatenate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.5.2.2.1.1.1.1) it with the string `' minutes'`.

```sql
delete from my_table
where expires < (to_timestamp($1) - ($2::text || ' minutes')::interval
```

UPDATE: actually, since postgres does have a `any || text` operator, the result of which is `text`, you shouldn't need to type cast the parameter.

Comment: I like the way you think! :)
If there's no actual/correct solution, this would be my go-to approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can also parametrize the entire interval string instead. This removes the need for an intermediate cast to `text` and concat.

```golang
query := `
  delete from my_table
  where expires < (to_timestamp($1) - $2::interval);
`
interval := fmt.Sprintf("%d minutes", mins)
db.Exec(query, timestamp, interval)
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it makes it clearest how you handle an interval of any unit of time (it handles minutes, hours, months, etc)